# change title for contactsUI 'forNewContact' swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, cncontact

I'm using contacts UI for adding new contact with this code

```
        let a = CNContact()
        let contactPickerViewController = CNContactViewController.init(forNewContact: a) // iOS Editor
        contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
        let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: contactPickerViewController)
        nav.title = "AppContact"
        self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want to make the nav bar title to be "AppContact" but it always get the default "New Contact". How to change the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigation bar grabs the title from the `UIViewController` that is presently on top of the navigation stack, In your case the `RootViewController`. Instead change the title property of that `UIViewController`

```
    let a = CNContact()
    let contactPickerViewController = CNContactViewController.init(forNewContact: a) // iOS Editor
    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
    let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: contactPickerViewController)
    contactPickerViewController.title = "AppContact" //Using currently presented ViewController .title property.
    self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is the discussion of the `title` property of from the `UIViewController` class reference provided by apple

Discussion:

`Set the title to a human-readable string that describes the view. If the view controller has a valid navigation item or tab-bar item, assigning a value to this property updates the title text those objects.`

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title) to `UIViewController` title documentation.